# Visual C++ 2015 debugger's STEP OVER jumps to strange positions in source code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-c++

I'm interested in CPython implementation, and want to read the source code of CPython. Therefore I download CPython 3.5.0 source code and use Visual C++ 2015 debugger to step through the code.

However, there is a very strange problem when I use the debugger to walk through the code. When the debugger gets into function `PyObject * PyEval_EvalFrameEx(PyFrameObject *f, int throwflag)` in Python/ceval.c, the next instruction pointer of the debugger starts to jump to strange positions.

For example, I use a break point to stop at line 1218 of Python/ceval.c
[image: Before I click STEP OVER]

Then I click STEP OVER, expecting the debugger goes to line 1221 of Python/ceval.c, but it goes to line 3501 of Python/ceval.c instead.
[image: After I click STEP OVER]

It looks like the compiler has rearranged instruction order, However I'm pretty sure that I'm in debug mode and all the optimizations are turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason.

The source code of python use some `#pragma optimize` in the code. Even though I compile it in debug mode, the optimization will be turned on automatically.

I cannot understand why the authors of python decide to do this, which can easily cause confusion for new comers.